# What would be the Alternative for SimpleNamingContextBuilder, since it is depricated?

Tags: spring, mocking, jndi

I have a Naming Builder class which registers the objects in the JNDI directory from a map. it is recommended by Spring to replace its own deprecated JNDI Mock implementation. Deprecated as of Spring Framework 5.2 in favor of complete solutions from third parties such as Simple-JNDI

```
import org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContextBuilder;

public class SMNContextBuilder implements InitializingBean{

    private Map ncMap;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        if (ncMap == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ncMap is null!");
        }

        SimpleNamingContextBuilder.emptyActivatedContextBuilder();
        bindObjects();

    }

    protected void bindObjects() {

        for (Iterator iter = ncMap.entrySet().iterator(); iter
                .hasNext();) {
            Map.Entry entryTmp = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
            SimpleNamingContextBuilder.getCurrentContextBuilder().bind(
                    "" + entryTmp.getKey(), entryTmp.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void setNamingContextMap(Map ncMapPar) {

        ncMap = ncMapPar;
    }
}
```

Then, I have a Test Config where this is used.

```
@Configuration
public class MQTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public SMNContextBuilder jnidInitializingBean() throws JMSException {

        SMNContextBuilder builder = new SMNContextBuilder ();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("java:comp/env/jms/My_ConFac", myConnectionFactory());
        map.put("jms/My_Queue", myQueue());

        builder.setNamingContextMap(map);

        return builder;
    }
```

What would be the Alternative of using SimpleNamingContextBuilder?

I have tried the following:

```
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class SMNContextBuilder implements InitializingBean{

    private Map ncMap;

    InitialContext ctx;

    public SimpleMapNamingContextBuilder() {
        try {
            this.ctx = new InitialContext();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        if (ncMap == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ncMap is null!");
        }

        SMNContextBuilder.emptyActivatedContextBuilder();
        bindObjects();

    }

    protected void bindObjects() {

        for (Iterator iter = ncMap.entrySet().iterator(); iter
                .hasNext();) {
            Map.Entry entryTmp = (Map.Entry) iter.next();

        try {
            ctx.bind(
                    "" + entryTmp.getKey(), entryTmp.getValue());
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    }

    public void setNamingContextMap(Map ncMapPar) {

        ncMap = ncMapPar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you point out in the question, Spring's recommendation is to use [Simple-JNDI](https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI).

Combing through the documentation, it doesn't look like there is a way to easily replace a class from this library into your current code, but it appears you can still accomplish what you want by loading your beans (in this case `myConnectionFactory()` and `myQueue()` into your `InitialContext` using `Properties`.  See [this section of the documentation](https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI/wiki/Programmatically-create-your-contexts-and-context-objects-(no-resource-files-needed)).

It does seem like the more common avenue is to configure your JNDI resources using .xml/.properties/.ini files.  There is a lot of documentation on how to do this in the Simple-JNDI github page (linked above)